# How to fix Rendering Problems in Android Studio?

Tags: android

Every time I got Rendering Problems after create new application.

My Rendering Problems is :

```
 Rendering Problems The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x1080029   at android.content.res.Resources.getResourceName(Resources.java:2235)   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2602)   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)   at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)   at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompatApi21.getDrawable(ContextCompatApi21.java:26)   at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:180)   at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:70)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:39)   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:65)   at android.support.design.widget.VisibilityAwareImageButton.<init>(VisibilityAwareImageButton.java:37)   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:109)   at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:105)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:835)   at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:70)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:811)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy stack to clipboard
```

Help me to out of there Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try **File->Invalidate Caches and Restart**. Works for me at times.

Answer (score 0):

These problem occur when your android studio didn't correctly load all the library in cache. to remove this you can use 
**File->Invalidate cashes and restart and choose invalidate and restart**.
Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same issue and resolved by changing design support lib version

Check your build.gradle

> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'

if you have this version, change it to

> compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

some times this 23.2 version is creating problem

Comment: The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.NavigationView (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.internal.view.SupportMenuInflater Copy stack to clipboard

Comment: this is after add 23.1

Comment: try to change your app theme, you will find this theme in top of preview. change it AppTheme to Material Light or any other and check hope it will work for you